# Iterate through list using next() and previous()

Tags: android, kotlin, collections, iterator

I have a list that i need to iterate through in both ways ,i used an iterator

```
teamIterator = data.listIterator()
```

and then i used the built-in function next() and previous to iterate

```
    fun next() {

    if (teamIterator.hasNext()) {
        selectedTechnician.postValue(teamIterator.next())
    }
}

fun previous() {

    if (teamIterator.hasPrevious()) {
        selectedTechnician.postValue(teamIterator.previous())
    }
}
```

the problem with this approach is that when clicking next at the beginning of the list it has to be two clicks , also after performing next and wanted to go previous i have to click two times on previous which is not good behaviour,
any way to avoid next() to not return actual item and only returns next item in the list ?

Comment: Any reason you can use indexed access?

Comment: what do you suggest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An iterator doesn't have the notion of a *current* element, so you're always between elements, and switching directions with your above algorithm will result in a repeated element.

You can use an index variable to track a current element index so you can always force a change when switching directions.

```
//Property
var currentIndex = 0

fun next() {
    if (currentIndex < data.lastIndex) {
        selectedTechnician.postValue(data[++currentIndex])
    }
}

fun previous() {
    if (currentIndex > 0) {
        selectedTechnician.postValue(data[--currentIndex])
    }
}
```

Comment: i eventually ended up iterating using indexation like that , thought kotlin built in iterator might do the job on its own